# SQLBulkCopy: Does Column Count make difference?

Tags: sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I try to search but didn't found answer to relative simple thing. I have a CSV, that doesn't have all the column as in my database table, as well as it miss the auto increment, primary key in CSV too.

All I did is I read CSV into the DataSet, and then run a traditional SQLBulkCopy code to read the first table of dataset to database table. But it give me following error:

`The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination.`

My code for bulkcopy is

```
using (SqlBulkCopy blkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(DBUtility.ConnectionString))
{

    blkcopy.EnableStreaming = true;
    blkcopy.DestinationTableName = "Project_" + this.ProjectID.ToString() + "_Data";
    blkcopy.BatchSize = 100;
    foreach (DataColumn c in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
    {
        blkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(c.ColumnName, c.ColumnName);
    }

    blkcopy.WriteToServer(ds.Tables[0]);
    blkcopy.Close();
}
```

I add Mapping to test, but it doesn't make difference to remove mapping part. If we remove mapping that it try to match column in order and since column are different in count they end up mismatch datatype and lesser column values etc. Oh yes the column names from CSV does match that from Table, and are in same case.

EDIT: I change the mapping code to compare the column name from live DB. For this I simply run a SQL Select query to fetch 1 record from database table and then do following

```
foreach (DataColumn c in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
{
    if (LiveDT.Columns.Contains(c.ColumnName))
    {
        blkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(c.ColumnName, c.ColumnName);
    }
    else
    {
        log.WriteLine(c.ColumnName + " doesn't exists in final table");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try breaking out of the foreach after mapping just a single column and see if you get the same error. If you don't, one of the other columns seems to not map correctly. You can always binary search for which one unless inspecting the exception gives you more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would dump the results of CSV into a staging SQL table...and then do a simple insert from staging table to production table.

also do a simple Import of CSV into SQL Table, maybe there are some empty/invalid columns within CSV file.

Comment: I love to follow your suggestion, but we are not very sure what columns we get from CSV, they can vary, and as I read or found the SQLBulkCopy does support missing column etc, but it is not the case with me. see my new edit if you got any other idea? If not then guess what I have to follow your path.

Comment: Also, I have to read multiple CSV, they all get about 1GB In size :), and we are doing it in parallel, creating new table for each read is not good as I understand.

Comment: my suggestion was to start with something simple, so you can at least be sure problem is NOT with CSV file, maybe your CSV file is qoma(,) delimited and somewhere in text you have qoma somewhere and it is breaking the format, dumping file into SQL manually using import export utility will give you some good ideas.

Comment: if format of ALL files is SAME (columns etc), then create only one staging table....insert data into it....process the data and then truncate the table right away.

Comment: all data is Float value and one column is dateTime, so no , in data. not all csv are same, some miss some column, we have about 50 columns and some file have 30, some have 45 or variable columns based on our source reading.

Comment: all of your files are failing to import using SQLBulkCopy or just the few files? did you try to import manually into SQL to investigate the issue?

Comment: Yes SQL import goes smooth for file and mapping of file was accurate with automation.

Comment: Your method at least make things going on, though they overall slow down the speed of import, previously it was taking 3 minute to import one file, now it is 4 minute. With Previous I mean I was creating a Dataset from Live Database table, and adding rows in it and then using Sqlbulk doing insert, but that fails on large dataset. However it works, and it is only way I find so far.

Comment: Bonus Tip: Bulk Sql insert is very fast way of loading data into SQL Server

Comment: Yeah I know that is why I am using it, just that staging table add additional burden and that I want to neglect. But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I once had this problem and the cause was a difference in the case of the column names. One of the columns was **"Id"**, but in the DB it was **"id"**.